# How to remove control may reach end of non void function using by typedef string in Xcode C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I am doing my homework and I got some files to do that and I have to modify the source code but I got an error from the source code that I got from my professor. I haven't checked whether this source code is working or not on Visual Studio but I guess this source code is working on Visual Studio. What should I do in this case?

```
`
    // return top of stack
    Elemty ArrayStack::top() {
        if (empty()) cout<<"Top of empty stack"<< endl;
        else return S[t];
    }
`
```

Comment: If `empty()` returns `true`, what do you return then? Not returning anything from a function declared to return a value leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: The error has been gone
Thank you

Comment: This code will generate warning with ANY compiler ... I would throw an exception if empty